# why my code make an infinite loop when I call the api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, infinite-loop, http-get

I'm trying to call my api to get the name of a tp but in the view I only see a `[object promise]` and in the browser console it looks like it's doing an infinite loop

html:

```
<table [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover" datatable>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Intitulé</th>
    <th>Résultat</th>
    <th>Coefficiant</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngIf="grades?.length != 0">
  <tr *ngFor="let grade of grades">
    <td>{{ formatDate(grade.Date) | date : 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm'}}</td>
    <td>{{ getTpName(grade.tp_id) }}</td>
    <td><b>{{ grade.Grade | number:'2.1-2' }}/20</b></td>
    <td>{{ grade.coeff | number:'1.1'}}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody *ngIf="grades?.length == 0">
  <tr>
    <td class="no-data-available" colspan="4">Aucune note enregistées</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

TS:

```js
  async getTpName(tp_id: any) {
    return  await this.apiService.getTpName(tp_id);
  }
```

apiservice>getTpName

```js
  getTpName(tp_id) {
    let url = `${this._tpUrl}/readName/${tp_id}`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(url, {headers: this.headers}).subscribe(
        res => resolve(res),
        error => reject(error)
      )
    });
  }
```

Do you know why it happen and how to correct this ?

EDIT:
[image: here's my network tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be good to move the api call from html to component controller.

```js
ngOnInit() {
   grades.forEach(grade => {
       this.getTpName(grade.tp_id)
           .pipe(take(1))
           .subscribe(tpName => {
                grade.tpName = tpName;
           });
   });
}
```

```html
< td > {{ grade.tpName | json }}</td >
```

Comment: with your code it now display a 'null' and the console is still looping infinitely

Comment: `the console is still looping infinitely` - what does it mean? if you go to network tab in developer console, do you see the requests?

Comment: yes endless request and if I console log in my method this.apiService.gettpname I got an object:
{
  "_isScalar": false,
  "source": {
    "_isScalar": false,
    "source": {
      "_isScalar": false,
      "source": {
        "_isScalar": false
      },
      "operator": {
        "concurrent": 1
      }
    },
    "operator": {}
  },
  "operator": {}
}

Comment: of course you will get the result with console.log because if's an observable not the result. are you sure your backend works? please attach the screenshot of your network tab if you can

Comment: done, then how do I extract the name from the observable ? and in my backend terminal I see a get response so I suppose it works

Comment: `getTpName(tp_id: any) {
  return  this.apiService.getTpName(tp_id).pipe(map(r => (console.log(r), r));
}`

Comment: please update the function like the above and see what you get in console.
you have to add `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: I get this {
  "name": "TP python n°1"
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217737/discussion-between-yash-and-lolo-zemadnessgamer).